# Obtain max-width using JS in px when it is defined in other units in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to obtain `max-width` in `px` to use it in a Javascript code but that may be defined in other units in CSS.
Do you have any ideas on how to obtain that using JS?

```js
const ele = document.querySelector("div")
const eleMaxWidth = window.getComputedStyle(ele).maxWidth
console.log(eleMaxWidth)
```

```css
div {max-width: 50%}
```

```html
<div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: as others had pointed out, there are no built-in ways to do that, so this is a very hacky work around. I've only test it on Chrome and Firefox, it may not work on other browser.

```js
const ele = document.querySelector("div");
const oldWidth = ele.style.width;
ele.style.width = '100000000cm'; /* = 1000km*/
const eleMaxWidth = ele.offsetWidth;
ele.style.width = oldWidth;
console.log(eleMaxWidth + 'px');
```

```css
div {
  max-width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Could you make width same as max-width just to avoid setting it to something huge (not that I think that matters as long as it’s within the bounds of an integer however the browser works it out).

Comment: @AHaworth I did try that, when the element has no max-width defined its width would be unset and default to its parent's width. (I don't think it matters either since OP should make sure there is a max-width set on the element before trying to convert it to px anyway)

Comment: Good point. I think your method works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetWidth` to get the total width of the parent div in pixels, and then derive the max-width of the needed div by multiplying it by the percentage you got earlier:

```js
const ele = document.querySelector("div")
const parentEle = ele.parentNode
let maxWidthPercentage = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(ele).maxWidth)/100;
console.log(maxWidthPercentage)
let derivedWidth = (parentEle.offsetWidth * maxWidthPercentage)
console.log(derivedWidth)

// offsetWidth for accuracy check
console.log(ele.offsetWidth)
```

```css
div {max-width: 50%}
```

```html
<div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but `offsetWidth` returns current width not max-width.

Comment: @PeterSH does it work to find the parent div's width in pixels and derive the needed div's max-width using the '50' returned by the code in your example?

Comment: I was looking for a direct solution to avoid any bugs in unexpected situations.

Comment: @PeterSH I've amended my answer, it should work for anything with a max-width property

Comment: I think the browser should convert the unit to be able to use it and there should be a way to obtain that value so I edited the question to be more general but if It is the only way I'll accept that.

Comment: @PeterSH I don't think there's a built-in javascript unit conversion from % to 'px', if that's what you're asking.  Pretty much everything will return maxWidth as the value you provided in the CSS (e.g. `style.maxHeight`, `getAttribute()`). I'm looking around at other StackOverflow answers and generally they do some division either with the parent div or the window width/height (and if they don't, they do a few calculations anyway).  I like using the parent div because the containing div is what the percentage is always targeting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254321/discussion-between-peter-sh-and-fordat).

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the percentage value by the width of its parent element.

```js
const 
    child = document.querySelector("#bar"),
    parent = child.parentNode,
    childMaxWidth = getComputedStyle(child).maxWidth.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "") / 100,
    parentWidth = getComputedStyle(parent).width.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
    
console.log(`
Child's max-width: ${childMaxWidth * 100}%
Parent's width: ${parentWidth}px
Child's max-width in px: ${childMaxWidth * parentWidth}px`);
```

```css
#foo{
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
}

#bar{
  max-width: 95%;
  max-height: max-content;
}
```

```html
<section id="foo">
  <p id="bar">Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question to be more general because I think the browser should convert the unit before using it and I want to obtain that.

Comment: @PeterSH As far as I know, there isn't such a property or native method which gives the [computed value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#computed-value) given in pixels of a percentage value. It's the browser's engine which internally does that task.